# Order of printing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

My code is simple as

```
df['col'].hist(bins = 250)
df['col'].value_counts()
```

What I don't understand, my output in my Jupyter notebook appears in reverse order.

[image]

If I change the order to

```
df['col'].value_counts()
df['col'].hist(bins = 250)
```

then just the histogramm appears.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Only the return value of the _last_ statement in a block will be printed below the block (unless terminated with `;`, then nothing is printed). Plots are a special case, see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hist() shows a visual figure while value_count() shows textual output. Unless otherwise specified, the visual data loads after textual data in a jupyter cell.

Add `plt.show()` after hist to refresh your window and show the visual plot before that.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that why I use "%matplotlib inline" in my first cell, to not call plt.show() every time? Sorry I forgot to mention in the question.

Comment: Good question. `%matplotlib inline` makes your plots appear as images and removes the interactive bar that allows you to zoom in, move the plot etc.
Try running with and without it to see the change.